# Click handler for main view in android

Tags: android, handler

Can we have setonclick listners for the main view, i mean setcontentview(main), can i have a click  handler for this. i tried but the listners were not responding for main view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,You can create it Like...

```
RelativeLayout rMain = (RelativeLayout)findviewById(R.id.mainlayout);
rMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //here you can do your code on click main....               
            }
        });
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-Any view is here->
   <Button/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with             @Override
its removing this, and thats why i cant have click handler.

Comment: All that @Override does is give you a compile-time error when you create the wrong method, instead of letting you deal with various run time errors and bugs that would arise from the mistake.